# Problems installing Scrapy on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, twisted, ubuntu-18.04

I am having trouble installing Scrapy on Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried for a long time to install it, and there seem to be problems with Twisted and some other packages.  I am now to programming, so any advice about the following messages in the command line would be appreciated:

```
Command "/home/.../bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-.../Twisted/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-_.../install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/.../python3.6/Twisted" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-yypirmho/Twisted/
```

I am also having the following problem when I tried to install python3-dev. The Scrapy Tutorial says to enter the following ([Scrapy Installation Instructions](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#intro-install)):

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-dev
```

I have python 3.6 on my computer and this is what I get when I try to install python3-dev with sudo:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-dev : Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.6.5-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3.6-dev (>= 3.6.5-2~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After some searching, I tried to use Pip3 to install python3-dev, and I got the following:

```
$ pip3 install python3-dev
Collecting python3-dev
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-dev (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python3-dev
```

Any advice about this would be appreciated, because I have spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem.

Comment: `sudo apt install python3-dev`

Comment: Thanks @UpasanaMittal. I tried that and still the message about unmet dependencies.